# Clojure - If based on Some result

Tags: if-statement, clojure

I want to start this post with an apology, I am entirely self tought and this is my first question, though I use Stackoverflow A LOT.

I want to make a decision based on the result of a `some` function...

```
(if (= nil (some (partial = (:activeboard (:boards app)))
                 (:otherboards (:boards app))))
  (om/transact! (:boards app) :activeboard (fn [_] active)))
```

I know the `some` test works as I have the same `some` function further down to output the result to the screen. But the `if` test does not. I have similarly tried a `case` and a `condp`. Nothing seems to evaluate the `some` function. The result of the `some` function is either `nil`, or `true`, so `if` should evaluate that??

Comment: considering your output is either nil or true you could remove `= nil` part as well. So `(when-not (some ..) :hooray!)`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about evaluating `some` within `if` and as far as I can tell your code is fine. Take a look below and see if you can construct something similar (that we can all try running ourselves) and that demonstrates the problem.

Case 1, activeboard is included in otherboard:

```
(def app {:boards {:activeboard 1 :otherboards [1 2 3]}})

(if (= nil (some (partial = (:activeboard (:boards app))) (:otherboards (:boards app))))
  (println "some returned nil")
  (println "some did not return nil"))
```

evaluated:

```
>> some did not return nil
```

Case 2, activeboard is not included in otherboard:

```
(def app {:boards {:activeboard 1 :otherboards [2 3 4]}})

(if (= nil (some (partial = (:activeboard (:boards app))) (:otherboards (:boards app))))
  (println "some returned nil")
  (println "some did not return nil"))
```

evaluated:

```
>> some returned nil
```

Comment: Thank you, though I wish my code was wrong :-( it would make fixing it easier.

Answer (score 1):

First, code indentation can go a long way in helping you to understand your own code. I edited your question to be at least a bit more clear.

Second, consider using the thread-first operator (`->`) or `get-in` to navigate through multiple levels in a map. But that's merely a code style thing.

Your condition looks fine, just as @jas already demonstrated. What could get you into trouble is that you do not provide an "else" path to your `if`. The `if` macro expects three "parameters": the condition, the "then" block and the "else" block. If you only want to test the truthy case of your condition, use `when`.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I was trying to figure out how to put it into a code block, but none of the options looked right. I was under ther impression, that you could just provide a then option and do nothing for the "else" block. I'll have a look at When and see is that a possibility.

Comment: You're right that `if` works fine without an "else" block, but many consider it better style to use `when` in that case.